# FB.ui method 'share': Detect fail or success

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the FB.ui version for my Facebook sharer. But somehow it seems that even when a user cancels the share-event, it will log a success.

My code looks like this:

```
window.FB.ui(sharer,
function (response) {
    if (response && !response.error_message) {
        $.post('/factor/shared/', {
            quiz: $('body').attr('id').split('-')[1],
            t: t
        });
        Site.log('%cSUCCESS', 'color: #00ff00');
    } else {
        Site.log('%cERROR', 'color: #ff0000');
    }
    window.location.href = window.appConfig.answerresult.forward_link;
});
);
```

The `sharer` looks like this:

```
var sharer = {
    method: 'share',
    href: $(this).data('sharelink') + "?p`enter code here`=" + params_to_base64(params),
};
```

Can you help me with this to make it work properly?

I have tried using these methods:

[Detect Facebook share success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181457/detect-facebook-share-success)

[How to detect Facebook share success? with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506213/how-to-detect-facebook-share-success-with-javascript)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: Why do you need to detect it?

Comment: @CBroe It's for analytics - it's interesting if a user actually completed the share process or if he cancelled it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#response